# Adding new path to .bash_profile; .bash_profile PATH different to echo $PATH

Tags: bash

My `.bash_profile` looks like:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/home/user/condor/bin:/home/user/merlin/bin

export PATH
```

I just added `:/home/user/merlin/bin` to my `PATH`

However when I echo $PATH I see the following:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/scoleman/bin:/home/scoleman/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/home/user/condor/bin:/home/user/scoleman/bin:/home/scoleman/bin
```

I don't see the new path that I added (`:/home/user/merlin/bin`) and is also different to what is in my .bash_profile

Ultimatly I'm trying to add the following new project path:

```
:/home/user/merlin/bin/strats/
```

But I'm now unsure as to where I should be adding the new path or if I should be doing something after I've added the new path to my `.bash_profile`?

Why does the `.bash_profile` script have a different set of paths compared to `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Did you relogin?

Comment: Hi, Mr Tux -  Yes, rebooted by environment

Comment: OSX or Linux? Are you actually using bash (no zsh, ksh...)?

Comment: Linux - edited the file using VIM

Comment: Have you tried to print `$PATH` after `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Is that the whole `.bash_profile`, is there anything after `export PATH`?  Are you sure you are running `bash` when you login?  Do a `ps` (no parameters) to make sure.

Comment: There is nothing after the 'export Path'. When I run ps I get:[user@localhost ~]$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2286 pts/0    00:00:08 bash
16736 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[user@localhost ~]$

Comment: How are you launching your session terminal? You connect via ssh to the system? You login locally through a GUI (Window manager)? `.bash_profile` is only for interactive login shells.